# How to prevent printing exception statements in Log files

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I am required to check whether a preexisting data base is present in my application, and for that I have written the following code:

```
    public boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = "/data/data/com.mycomp.sampleapp/databases/myDB.db";
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                } 
        catch (Exception e) {   }
return checkDB != null ? true : false;

    }
```

The above code working as expected. Now my problem is that it is printing below exception statements in my Logcat. I just want to do nothing and don't want to print exception in my Logcat.

```
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.mycomp.sampleapp/databases/myDB.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:338)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:232)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:885)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:855)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at com.mycomp.sampleapp.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:63)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at com.mycomp.sampleapp.GetData.doInBackground(GetData.java:55)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at com.mycomp.sampleapp.GetData.doInBackground(GetData.java:1)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/SQLiteDatabase(27655):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have written my code in try/catch block, but still it's printing the exception in my log files.

The exception is generating from the below statement of my code:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Please let me know how can I prevent printing exception in log files.

Comment: what is your package name?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether file exists:

```
File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(myPath);
boolean exists = dbFile.exists();
```

For your example:

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "myDB.db";

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_PATH);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but my question is that how prevent printing exception logs. My code working as expected.

Comment: You can't prevent printing out exception in Logcat because exception is not thrown, just printed. SQLite does that behind the scenes.

Comment: If you want to prevent that, you will have to change your code. Check updated answer.